# enable only two next months in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to enable only next two months in date picker.
like if current month is February,then only march and April should enable in date picker.all other month should disable.

I have tried number of Months, but it shows two months inline.I don't want to display like this.

I have tried this,

```
        minDate: '0',
        maxDate: '+2m+30d',
```

but, it changes according to date,

I need only two months exactly from current month.

Is there any other solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like following

```js
$(function () {
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 2))
    });
});
```

```html
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtFrom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try code or go to the link

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y67W/337/)

HTML-

```
<input id="date" />
```

JAVASCRIPT-

```
$("#date").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  minDate:0,
  maxDate: "+3M"
}).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Comment: -in this code also set date after 90 days.based on today it will display upto 9o days.that is upto may 31.But what happen on next day.it will again take 90 days from current date then,it will go to june.

Comment: @Reshma I have updated my code and it selects next 3 months from current date.

Comment: In your code selects next 3 months ,that is upto 1st june. from current date,but if i check in tomorrow then it will be upto 2 nd june? I need to display only next 3 months from current month whtever be the date.  from 1st march to 31 st march only april and upto may 31 st should selected.

Comment: @Reshma I have updated my answer may be it can help you. It will take only 3 months from current month and not depend what will be the value of date in current month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are adding +30d as well . which will be 3 months from today . also i guess space would be required between `'+2m +30d'`

```
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ maxDate: "+2M" });
```

Comment: but it will changes according to current date.in all conditions i need to display only next two months.please help with this

Comment: @Reshma Do you want to add any static dates? Means 2 months from today will be 6th May calender will calculate 2 months from date the have as a parameter?.